# How to send a MemoryStream from Blazor Webassembly app to .NET API endpoint?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, file-upload, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a component in my Blazor WASM app that gets a signature from the user and makes it a png file. I get the bytes from the JavaScript component and create a MemoryStream. But when I send it to the backend, I have no bytes, even though they are there on the front-end.
The way I have it set up works fine for a file upload. I'm doing this in another component. That gets an IBrowserFile then creates a MultipartFormDataContent object and that goes through with no problem. But the signature image loses the bytes along the way.

Here are the methods for the client:

```
    private async Task SaveSignatureAsync(byte[] imageBytes)  
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream .Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");

        var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream , Convert.ToInt32(stream .Length));
        streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");

        content.Add(streamContent, "image", "signature.png");
        _imageUrl = await PicUploadHttpRepository.UploadImage(content);
    }
```

This is the HTTP service:

```
        public async Task<string> UploadImage(MultipartFormDataContent content)
        {
            var response = await _httpService.PostForm(_apiUrl, content);
            string jsonString = await response.GetBody();
            if (!response.Success)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(jsonString);
            }

            PicUploadResponse picUploadResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PicUploadResponse>(jsonString);            
            return picUploadResponse is not null ? picUploadResponse.FileURL : string.Empty;
        } 



        public async Task<HttpResponseWrapper<object>> PostForm(string url, MultipartFormDataContent content)
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            return new HttpResponseWrapper<object>(null, response.IsSuccessStatusCode, response);
        }
```

And this is the API endpoint:

```
        [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var formCollection = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
                var file = formCollection.Files.First();
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    // use guid for file name
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    var blobFileName = $"{ Guid.NewGuid() }{ fileExtension.ToLower() }";

                    string fileURL = await uploadService.UploadAsync(file.OpenReadStream(), blobFileName, file.ContentType, _imageBlobContainerName);
                    return Ok(new { fileURL });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
            }
        }
```

I have it set up the same way with the IBrowserFile that gets selected by the user. That works fine. But it's not working with the MemoryStream. Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: I replaced

```var stream = new MemoryStream();
 stream .Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);```

With 
```await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray);```
That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but for future references. After writing to the MemoryStream, the position is at the end of the stream, hence no more data are available.

Can be fixed by setting position to 0:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
stream.Position = 0;
```